# code cademy Jeykll: Initialze your repo

Tags: jekyll

I am trying Deploy a Website using Jekyll: 
Initialize Your Repo
the error msg: "Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/ccuser/workspace/daw/.git/"?

Comment: Could you please add the link you are using as a reference for other users to be able to help you better? Consider adding more detail to your question so we have a better idea of your problem.

Comment: It seems that you've cloned an example repository. Which one ?